# Probability for a 'pair' to occur when rolling 5 dice

Tags: probability, binomial-coefficients

5 fair dice are rolled. A pair is defined to be any number that shows up twice, while the rest of the dice show different numbers (to the number on the pair and to each other). I am looking for the probability of a pair occurring.

My thoughts are that the number of choices for the repeated number (the pair) is $6$, the number of choices for the next number is $5$ then the next number $4$, then $3$. So the total number of choices I have for the possible combination of 6 unique numbers for 5 dice (with $1$ repeated) is $6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3$. Therefore for combination above, the number of ways to rearrange the the two identical numbers that form the pair is $\binom{5}{2}$ so the total number of pairs that exist is:
$$\binom{5}{2}6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3$$
I am wondering if this is the right way to count the number of combinations that form a pair?

Comment: HINT: forget numbers and think it as subsets or groups. Pair and what is not pair.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are ${6\choose4}$ ways to choose the four numbers which appear. Once this choice is made, there are $4$ ways to choose the number appearing twice. Once these choices are made, there are ${5\choose2}$ ways to choose the places where the number appearing twice appears. Once all these choices are made, there are $3!$ ways to choose the places where the other three numbers appear.

Since there is a total of $6^5$ results, the desired probablility is $$\frac1{6^5}\cdot{6\choose4}\cdot4\cdot{5\choose2}\cdot3!=\frac{25}{54}\approx46.3\%.$$
This is the number you suggest in your question, only, motivated differently.

Comment: This result seems odd. I'm not saying it isn't correct because I find no flaw in your logic, but my intuition says the probability must be higher than $50%$. you roll $5$ dice. it can't be the probability for a pair is this low. consider the case where you roll $7$ dice. then the probability is $100%$ for a pair. this seems too low. would you mind looking at my answer and saying why is it wrong?

Comment: @OriaGruber Probability of exactly one pair $\ne$ Probability of at least one repeated result.

Comment: @OriaGruber A python script I quickly conjured up confirms this answer. You gave the answer of at least 1 pair. I asked for exactly 1 pair.

Comment: Ah yes, if you are looking for exactly $1$ pair, then I agree. good solution, upvoted.

Comment: OP: I guess "You" in the second sentence of your comment is user @OriaGruber.

Comment: How does the answer change if I want a specific pair.  For example(s)...
* Exactly (2) 1s (a pair of aces)
* (2) or more 1s (a pair or more of aces)

?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to think of the probability of a pair not occuring. This means that for the first dice we have $6$ options. for the second we have $5$ since what we got from the first one isn't allowed etc. overall thats $6*5*4*3*2=720$

And there are total of $6^5=7776$ combinations

So overall there are $7776-720=7056$ combinations with at least 1 pair.

Comment: This counts more than 1 pair (wording on the OP suggests exactly 1 pair).

Comment: ohh I see...yes that is correct.